# Excel macro error saying "Automation Error" when using WMI

Tags: excel, vba, wmi

I'm trying to run the below-mentioned code in VB(Excel Macro)  but I'm stuck with an error that pops up on running saying "Automation Error".

```
strComputer = "."

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='U:\'} Where " _ 
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")
For Each objFile In colFiles
       if objFile.FileName = "ml_*" Then
           destinationPROD = "X:\ABC\" & objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension
           objFile.Copy(destinationPROD)
           objFile.delete
       else
           destinationPROD = "X:\PQR\" & objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension
           objFile.Copy(destinationPROD)
           objFile.delete
       End If
Next
```

Comment: Could you format the code? Also change the title to include enough information? Automation Error when using WMI from VBA? Also, add the WMI tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another slash after "winmgmts:\" :)

It should be:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a rights problem. Test it using a local disk. Make sure that all required directories exist.